# window.open(url) print url in new tab rather than opening the url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.open

I have the following code that retrieves an url and then tries to open the url in a new page:

```
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.text)
.then(result => window.open(result, "__blank"))
```

As a result I get a new window with the url printed in the blank page rather than the url. 
I tried with www.google.com and I get "www.google.com" printed.

Comment: Did you mean `.then(res => res.text())`?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand it, something like that shouldn't even be possible in modern browsers, because it would make cross-site-scripting possible.

Comment: Yes, I mean `res.text()`

Comment: unclear how result would be a URL.

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean? I receive a string from fetch that is the URL I would like to open in an other page?

Comment: What is exactly the response? `console.log(escape(result))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full url. When tried this myself "www.google.com" didn't work but "https://www.google.com/" did. I think that's your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this on my local server and it worked fine in chrome

```js
window.open("https://google.com","new window")
```

Comment: Tried it, I get the same unexpected behaviour